# What does :: operator mean in C++ when it's used at the beginning

Tags: c++

```
  double timestamp = ::a::b::c::NowInSeconds();
```

Already know the use of :: in varible selection, but what's the meaning of it when it is used at the beginning and followed with a function (with namespace specified) ?

Comment: Global variable , it's used for accessing global variables

Comment: variable is in global scope

Comment: Does this answer your question? [:: scope resolution operator in front of a template function call in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937824/scope-resolution-operator-in-front-of-a-template-function-call-in-c)

Comment: "Look up the name that follows via the qualified name lookup in the global namespace".

Answer (score 3):

The initial `::` is used to explicitly specify that the name following it is located in the global/default namespace, and not in any other namespace that happens to be in scope.  Here's an example of how that might be useful:

```
int a;

namespace b {
   int a;
};

using namespace b;

int main(int, char **)
{
   a = 5;   // error, reference to 'a' is ambiguous

   ::a = 5;   // ok
}
```